# Shopify Hamburger Menu Button Not Working On Mobile Devices (Debut Theme)

Tags: menu, shopify

I'm using the Debut theme on my Shopify site and have an issue with the hamburger menu button not working. It will work once but when I navigate to a new page nothing happens when I press the button again. When the page loads the following message is shown on the console for theme.js:

```
TypeError: $.debounce is not a function. (In '$.debounce(50, function() {
styleDropdowns($(selectors.siteNavHasDropdown));
positionFullWidthDropdowns();
})', '$.debounce' is undefined)
```

If I manually empty caches through the browser and reload the page the error no longer appears in the console and the button works again. However, once I navigate away from the page the issue returns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have your JS files included on all pages